# Dynamic Widgets via for loop, not able to change the state of the other button

Tags: flutter

I am  trying to build series of widgets using For loop, the outcome of the for loop inserts widgets in a list and then I am using Row to render it in the UI

The problem is when I use ontap, I am not able to control other widgets

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1QAA.png)

I am able to select both the buttons and I am not able to deselect the other one

code link -
https://github.com/vinothkumarinc/sampleflutter/blob/main/add_parts.dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and was not able to replicate your problem. I can select and deselect any of the buttons. What I noticed however is that you have to click the text for `onTap` to trigger. If this is the root of the issue, consider replacing your `ItemGroupCreator` widget with the following:

```
class _ItemgroupcreatorState extends State<Itemgroupcreator> {
  Color selectcolor = Color(0xFF131d48);
  Color selecttext = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
  Color deselectcolor = Color(0xFFf3f3f3);
  Color deselecttext = Color(0xFF131d48);
  bool clicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          clicked ? clicked = false : clicked = true;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        width: 80.0,
        height: 30.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
          color: clicked ? selectcolor : deselectcolor,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              widget.itemgroupname,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: clicked ? selecttext : deselecttext,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: May be post owner want to do his list of widget like radio group behaviour. when he select one widget, other selected widget will change to deselected.

Comment: Hey Guys Thank you for your response, the problem I had with this approach was, each widget is storing the state separately and then it is remembering the clicks inside each state.